# 3V3 to 5V level conversion

Tags: level-shifting, logic-level, level-translation

I'm currently working on the development of some measurement equipment. For conversions I use a small ARM which runs on 3V3 and to display the results I use a graphical display running on 5V. This means that I have to shift the voltage levels from 3V3 to 5V and vice versa.

I have done some research on the topic and found out that there are numerous circuits on stackexchange alone (let go on the whole internet) to do it but I'm interested in how professional developers do it and how to achieve fast switching speeds for fast interfaces.

There is always the option to use a level shifter IC[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OI6k.jpg) but those are expensive and most companies may want to avoid additional component cost. People have done it bidirectional with just a 2N7002 and two resistors[2] whereas other people did it with a transistor and two resistors configured as an inverter.

How do professional developers shift the voltage level from 3V3 to 5V logic and vice versa? I have never seen level converters in a professional product (except for chargepumps for RS232 and such) - Do they just connect 3V3 and 5V logic?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OI6k.jpg)For example the SN74AVCB164245VR from TI

[2]

[image: circuit]

Comment: 5V TTL logic high level will easily accept 3V3 as a high and obviously 0V is a low.

Comment: Professionals do not stick to one method for all cases, but weigh the pros and cons of the various methods to find the best fit for their application and requirements.

Comment: What are your specific requirements? Can you quantify "fast switching speeds for fast interfaces"? Is your interface bi-directional? Is your 3V3 logic 5V tolerant?

Comment: In case you suspect that the logic levels actually matter for the display, and assuming you have several data lines (SPI?), you could use something like [74LVC245](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/302/74LVC_LVCH245A-70410.pdf).

Comment: I've heard about 5V logic level accepting 3V3 as HIGH. But then I have heard that some displays and other things like SPI interfaces do not accept the 3V3 as high for unknown reasons. I don't want to risk that. Yes, I'm using SPI and an 8080 compatible interface. My question was as specific as I could get without narrowing something down to my specific usecase.

Comment: The reasons are not 'unknown': they are stated in the datasheet(s)!

Comment: Unknown to me as I didn't ask further questions.

Comment: How fast are you driving it?  Is it bi-directional?  How cheap does it need to be?  You need to know all of those to make the decision.  To do it one-way there are lots of cheap options, e.g. some fets, or some cheap generic logic (74HC etc).  To go bi-drectional you can use a trick with a FET to be very cheap, or a level shifter if you have a few cents to spend.  If it needs to be super fast then you are more constrained.

Comment: @user2628088 "My question was as specific as I could get without narrowing something down to my specific usecase." ... Unless you can provide specifics, this question is too broad. Wouter's solution MAY be totally viable if your pins are 5V tolerant, can be put in open-drain mode, and you pull-up to 5V. If you can't find this in the datasheet, provide a link to it and tell us what pins you are using.

Comment: Alright then. I have two specific usecases. One is an old graphics (LC) display that I need to keep. It has an 8080 interface and needs 5V (not so high speed). On the other hand I have a Tiva C series ARM (129, not 123) which is not 5V tolerant on its pins that needs to talk with the 5V display. On the other hand I have a DAC814 DAC which detects a HIGH state from +2V up to (Vcc-1.4V) which results in 3.4V depending on the temperature. To be absolutely sure it works I want to translate the levels for the SPI interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using the 4-channel bidirectional [TXS0104E](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0104e.pdf) in a commercial product, and it is working very well for us.

In our case it is being used to convert from 3.3v to 1.8v and vice versa, but it can also be used to convert from 5v to 3.3v and vice versa (actually the high side can be anywhere from 2.3v to 5.5v, and the low side from 1.65v to 3.6v).

The chip also includes ESD protection on all pins.

It is available [from Digi-Key](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TXS0104EPWR/296-20697-1-ND/1143681) in a 14-TSSOP package for $1.87 in single quantities (73 cents in 1000's).  It is also available in an itsy-bitsy (1.9 x 1.4 mm) 12-DSBGA package.  That's about the same size as an 0805 resistor.  So you can easily fit them inline on top of a parallel bus going between chips.  The pins are nicely arranged in order on both sides of the chip to accommodate this.

Answer (score 1):

My experience with HD44780 and  S6B0107/S6B0108 (= KS0107B/KS0108B) based displays is that they don't work with 3.3V logic levels.

I put a 1k pull-up resistor on each pin and use the pins of an LPC1114 in open-drain mode. This works fine for me.

A professional will do what is appropriate for the situation. IME a high-volume design will combine a 3V uC with a 3V display. For low-cost designs you could check the Nokia 5510-style LCDs.

Comment: Just for clarity, is your recommendation to pull up to 5V (with a 5V tolerant pin of course)?

Comment: How can I recommend for a situation that I don't know? I tell what I did and what worked for me.

Comment: Of course you can't. I was just asking for clarification on your particular solution. Sometimes pull-ups are used to the same logic level (3V3) to achieve the full output voltage.

Comment: They can be used that way, but with open-drain (or switch out+low/input) pins that are 5V tolerant you can do level shifting this way. Note that in my case it did not work with plain outputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is usefull. It's a guide from nxp on levelshifting i2c lines with two mosfets.

http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10441.pdf

Comment: I2C lines are open-drain and bi-directional, which makes levels shifting such lines are very special case. in other words: can be used, but likely overkill.