# I2C level conversion (ESP32 and sensor)

Tags: sensor, i2c, esp32

I am trying to connect [ESP32 Feather board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3405) and [Thermal camera module](https://www.mouser.ee/datasheet/2/307/en_D6T_catalog-1633759.pdf) using I2C. ESP uses 3V3 and the sensor uses 5V I2C, thus I figured I need a I2C voltage conversion chip. I chose the [PCA9306 Breakout board](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11955). I connected everything up as shown in the [PCA9306 datasheet](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1805226.pdf) and even used examples from [this](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/pca9306-level-translator-hookup-guide). Every time the magic smoke comes out...

I have spent days trying to figure out why it is not working. Read datasheet twice. Re-soldered a new PCA93006 chip 5 times now. Looked at the schematics. Measured every trace with multimeter to ensure all connections are as they should on the breakout board. I drew a schematic how ESP32 and thermal sensor is connected to the PCA9306 breakout board. I really hope someone can tell me what am I doing wrong here. Simple circuit, but I really do not understand why it's not working.

Some notes about the schematic: if I only connected 5V and GND, then everything is fine, but as soon as I connect 3V3 to Vref1, then the magic smoke comes out.

[image]

The PCA9306 breakout schematic is here:
[image]

I have looked other questions related to [9306 chips](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/397726/using-a-pca9306-voltage-leveler-with-an-mcu-and-a-5-5v-arduino-sensor) and [I2C conversions](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/105218/3v3-to-5v-level-conversion), but I have not found an answer to my question.

EDIT 1: Smoke comes out from the PCA9306 chip on the breakout board.

EDIT 2: I added the testing wiring. I am using breadboard and USB power supply that provides me 5.1V and 3V3 to test the chip. If I power the circuit in the picture then the chip burns. Although, if I switch the vref1 voltage to 5.1V and vref2 to 3V3 and power the circuit then it works, but vref2 is outputting 3.8V. Thus, the voltage difference between vref1 and vref2 is 1.3V. Why is it working this way and if I switch the vref voltages, then the chip burns. As I understand I can't use the 3.8V, because it might damage the ESP32?

[image]

Comment: The smoke comes out from where? PCA9306? I think you need to post some photos, the schematics don't explain the smoke.

Comment: I edited the question and uploaded the picture.

Comment: Are those solder blobs shorting pins 1-4?  It's hard to tell from your photo (post a better image).  I haven't noticed anything of concern on your schematic.  Likely an issue with the PCB design, assembly (soldering), or external connections.

Comment: An image of the chip, where one can read the markings (a new, uninstalled chip would be ok), might help as well. Did you purchase the chip from a reputable source?

Comment: I think you better show how you connected it. As it is now, we only see the diagram about the plan, not how it actually was.

Comment: There are no shorts, I just checked. New chips (PCA9306DCUR) I got from Farnell. I edited my post and uploaded picture of the wiring with comments

Comment: The schematic and board look correct. How have you determined the correct orientation of the chip?

Comment: Well, it started working for some reason. I really don't know what I changed. Chip orientation was correct.